# Class to convert differently if casting to sequence or mapping

Tags: python, class, dictionary, tuples

Consider the following **toy** class:

```py
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __iter__(self):
        yield ('a', self.a)
        yield ('b', self.b)

x = Something(1, 2)

print(tuple(x))
# (('a', 1), ('b', 2))
print(dict(x))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

However, I would like it to behave like the following:

```py
print(tuple(x))
# (1, 2)
print(dict(x))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

How could I do that?

---

## EDIT

I am well aware that this could be achieved explicitly, e.g. (following `dict()` naming conventions):

```py
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def items(self):
        yield ('a', self.a)
        yield ('b', self.b)

    def values(self):
        yield self.a
        yield self.b
```

BUT clearly some objects do behave differently when casted to `dict()` or `tuple()` respectively. For example, the behavior of `dict()` itself (but also, for example, `collections.OrderedDict` and other mappings in the `collections` module) do something similar (uses *keys* while I would like to get *values*) just fine:

```py
import collections

dd = collections.OrderedDict((('a', 1), ('b', 2)))

print(dict(dd))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}

print(tuple(dd))
('a', 'b')

print([x for x in dd])
['a', 'b']
```

## EDIT 2:

Another way of seeing this is that when something goes through `dict()` EITHER it behaves differently depending on the `type` of `__iter__` OR looks like sometimes it relies on `__iter__` and sometimes it relies on *something else*. The question is what is that *something else* (or what kind of `type` checks happen at this level), how to get access to this alternate behavior and eventually discussing potential limitations.

I could well be that at the end of the day a custom class `Something` behaving as I described cannot be crafted in Python, because e.g. `__iter__` must return the keys of the mapping.

Comment: My gut says "You can't," but my head says "You shouldn't."

Comment: notice the even the builtin python `dict` type iterates only one way (by keys), and provides different methods to iterate over key-value pairs, or just values.

Comment: @AdamSmith why shouldn't I? Python developers clearly thought they should, since even built-in types behave differently when using `dict()` or `tuple()` on them e.g. `dd = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` and `dict(dd) == {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` while `tuple(dd) == ('a', 'b')` (or `import collections; dd = collections.OrderedDict((('a', 1), ('b', 2)))`) just to avoid the likely shortcut of *do-nothing* behavior for `dict(dict)`.

Comment: @norok2 but that behavior is defined in the logic of the built-ins (`dict` and `tuple`). You can't change those, you can only change the type, and the type has no concept of "When I'm being converted to a tuple, do _this_." You can define how the object is iterated over, but not how the built-in uses that data.

Comment: In other words you can decide that you're iterating to `('a', 1) ('b', 2)` and you'll get what you see, or you can decide that you're iterating to `1 2` and you'll get the tuple result you want, but not both. And importantly: even if you _could_ do both, you _shouldn't_ because it makes your type behave badly. Callers can't expect it to be consistent, which is Bad.

Comment: @AdamSmith I am not quite sure I am understanding your point, but see edits

Comment: @norok2 to your edit, you can definitely iterate over values. `def __iter__(self): yield from [self.a, self.b]`. Note that you lose the dictionary behavior you want when you do that. _You can't keep both._ You're confusing logic established in the calling code (the `dict(...)` call) with logic established in the object (the `Something(1, 2)`)

Comment: @AdamSmith why `collections.OrderedDict` can keep both behaviors?

Comment: @norok2 best guess is because an OrderedDict _is_ a dictionary. You can see the source yourself https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py

Comment: I think if this behavior would be possible then functions like `asdict` and `astuple` wouldn't exist in [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

Comment: @norok2 according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) I was correct in my assumption. Since `collections.OrderedDict` inherits from `dict`, `dict` knows enough about it to use custom logic ("If no positional argument is given, an empty dictionary is created. If a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping object. Otherwise...")

Comment: @norok2 I understand what you mean, but even `dict` implement a specific method to achieve a different behavior than `__iter__`... If you want to stick to the way builtin are made, why not simply implement a `items()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Either you declare dedicated methods:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def to_dict(self):
        return dict(self)

    def to_tuple(self):
        return tuple((y for _, y in self))

    def __iter__(self):
        yield ('a', self.a)
        yield ('b', self.b)

x = Something(1, 2)

print(x.to_tuple())
# (1, 2)
print(x.to_dict())
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Or you modify a little the way you convert your class to a tuple:

```
print(tuple((y for _, y in x)))
# (1, 2)
print(dict(x))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

> But the behaviour you would like your class to have would lead to a very tricky stituation, where the output of your `__iter__` method would be different following the type you are converting this output afterward...

Comment: "But the behaviour you would like your class to have would lead to a very tricky stituation, where tuple(dict(x)) would be different from tuple(x)" `dict()` why is that tricky? even with your class `tuple(dict(x)) != tuple(x)`...

Comment: Oh right, that was a mistake, I edited my answer (of course tuple(dict(x)) is different from tuple(x))...

Comment: And by tricky, I mean this is not the behaviour you would expect for an iterable. Your `__iter__` method here behaves like the `items()` method of a dict, returning (key, value) tuples. This should not change according to the type you are converting your object to, right?

Comment: `dict()` does precisely that and we all live just fine, though

Comment: no, `dict` return a dict object. The `dict().__iter__()` method only yield the dictionnary keys, while the `items` method returns (key, val) tuples and the `__repr__` method print a nice `{k: v, ...}` string.

Comment: OK, right the `__iter__` method itself does not change, but obviously when `dict(x)` is called, sometimes it relies on `__iter__` and sometimes relies on something else. The question is how can I access that something else, if possible, and what could be the limitations to that.

Answer (score 0):

One way can be this, but it needs explicit attribute change.

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def s(self, boolean):
        self.y = boolean
        return self
    def __iter__(self):
        if self.y:
            yield ('a', self.a)
            yield ('b', self.b)
        else:
            yield (self.a)
            yield (self.b)


x = Something(1, 2)
```

Outputs:-

```
print(tuple(x.s(0)))
# (1, 2)

print(dict(x.s(1)))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```